# Looking for a error message to the user is notinvoice

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
          collector.on("collect", async (i) => {
              i.deferReply({ ephemeral: true }).catch(() => {});
              if (!interaction.member.voice.channel)
                return i.followUp({
                  content:
                    emojis.error + ` | **You Must Join A Voice Channel**`,
                  ephemeral: true,
                });
              if (interaction.guild.me.voice.channel) {
                if (
                  interaction.member.voice.channel?.id !==
                  interaction.guild.me.voice.channel?.id
                )
                  return i.followUp({
                    content:
                      emojis.error +
                      ` | **You Must Join <#${interaction.guild.me.voice.channel.id}> To Contolr The Panel**`,
                    ephemeral: true,
                  });
              }
              
              -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
              
              else if (panelType == "reactions") {
            if (!interaction.member.voice.channel)
              return interaction.channel
                .send(emojis.error + ` | **You Must Join A Voice Channel**`)
                .then((m) => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    m.delete();
                  }, 1500);
                });
            if (interaction.guild.me.voice.channel) {
              if (
                interaction.member.voice.channel?.id !==
                interaction.guild.me.voice.channel?.id
              )
                return interaction.channel
                  .send(
                    emojis.error +
                      ` | **You Must Join <#${interaction.guild.me.voice.channel.id}> To Contolr The Panel**`
                  )
                  .then((m) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      m.delete();
                    }, 1500);
                  });
            }
```

anyone can help please .. I want the user when he types the prefix while he play.. I want the user to get a error message that he can't play that song if he is not in the some channel.. this code does not execute it can someone fix it to me

Comment: I am still looking for someone to help me... :)

Comment: Did you use the proper intent `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` ?

Comment: yes I did but it does not make sense the user still gets to the  side that the song is played when I am even in a another channel, I want him to get a error message like saying "You Must Be in the Some Voice Channel" something like that..

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if ()` statement:

```js
if (message.guild.me.voice.channel && message.member.voice.channel.id !== message.guild.me.voice.channel.id) return message.reply({content: 'you must be in the same voice channel as me'})
```

Or you can use `.some()` method to return a boolean, like:

```js
const sameChan = client.voice.connections.some((c) => c.channel.id === msg.member.voice.channelID)
if (!sameChan) return message.reply({content: 'you must be in the same voice channel as me'})
```

I recommend using the first choice though

Comment: i did like you said i get errors... can you check my code bellow..

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting on your console?

Comment: I really don't know.. its not the fact that its error, maybe its my problem, can you check the code bellow if its right settled or not..

Answer (score 0):

```
collector.on("collect", async (i) => {
             i.deferReply({ ephemeral: true }).catch(() => {});
             if (!interaction.member.voice.channel)
               return i.followUp({
                 content:
                   emojis.error + ` | **You Must Join A Voice Channel**`,
                 ephemeral: true,
               });
             if (interaction.guild.me.voice.channel) {
               if (message.guild.me.voice.channel && message.member.voice.channel.id !== message.guild.me.voice.channel.id) 
return message.reply({content: 'you must be in the same voice channel as me'})
             }});
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
else if (panelType == "reactions") {
           if (!interaction.member.voice.channel)
             return interaction.channel
               .send(emojis.error + ` | **You Must Join A Voice Channel**`)
               .then((m) => {
                 setTimeout(() => {
                   m.delete();
                 }, 1500);
               });
           if (interaction.guild.me.voice.channel) {
               if (message.guild.me.voice.channel && message.member.voice.channel.id !== message.guild.me.voice.channel.id) return message.reply({content: 'you must be in the same voice channel as me'})
             };
                 .then((m) => {
                   setTimeout(() => {
                     m.delete();
                   }, 1500);
                 });
           }
```

Comment: @Christy, here is the code i mention in the comments.. I did like you said but still does not give a error message to the player..